# require(): Failed opening required No such file or directory in /storage/ssd3/553/11626553/public_html/index.php

Tags: php, html, html5, bootstrap-4, hosting

Subí mi proyecto a un host gratuito y al momento de abrir mi archivo index.php me muestra error en las ligas de Bootstrap que estoy jalando desde una carpeta externa. Dicha linea de código es:

```
 <?php require 'complementos\ligasBootstrap.php' ?>
```

Las ligas de Bootstrap en mi carpeta "Complementos":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es un problema con la ruta.
Deberías reemplazar el require por: `require_once('../complementos/ligasBootstrap.php');` o `require_once('complementos/ligasBootstrap.php');` dependiendo donde se encuentre la carpeta en relación al archivo que lo está ejecutando.

Comment: Esto me ha servidor, muchas gracias por tu ayuda¡